# mfc120.dll missing for an application built in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dll, mfc, release

I have a VC++ based application developed in VS2010 which uses some of the win32 component. I ported the code in VS2013 and I built the code after removing all compilation error in Release Mode. Now when I am trying to run the exe in Computer where VS2013 is installed it is working fine where as it is giving an error of mfc120.dll is missing where only VS2010 is installed. I don't think after building the code in Release mode I should get an error of missing dll. I have not tried to run the exe where no Visual Studio is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution for this problem. Basically the win32 code I was building was using the Configuration Properties->General-> 'Use MFC in a Shared DLL' which I changed to 'Use MFC in a Shared DLL'. All working fine there after

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DLL version of the MFC you also need to install the corresponding VS-2013 runtime DLLs [vsredist_x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Or you switch to a complete static build.

Comment: I have installed and tried to build application. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Use Depends to check what DLLs are searched and missing. Where can you find the MFC120.DLL?

Comment: I suppose you are building a 32 bit application: So, you have installed the vs_redist_x86 and the mfc120.dll is showing up in your windows\system32 directory (on 64bit systems windows\SysWOW64 directory)?